# How to query for multiple invoices with quickbooks QBXML InvoiceQueryRq?

Tags: php, quickbooks, qbxml

I'm using PHP to generate QBXML to query quickbooks to find an invoice record. This is working. However, now I want to query for two different invoice RefNumbers.

This is my current code to query one invoice:

```
$qbxml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="2.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
         <InvoiceQueryRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
          <RefNumber>' . $ID . '</RefNumber>
          <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
        </InvoiceQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>';
```

How would I format it to search for RefNumber = $ID OR RefNumber = $ID2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the QuickBooks OSR documentation:

https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

You can see that `RefNumber` is documented as:

```
<RefNumber >STRTYPE</RefNumber> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
```

Key words there:

```
may repeat
```

So:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="11.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
         <InvoiceQueryRq requestID="abc1234">
          <RefNumber>1</RefNumber>
          <RefNumber>2</RefNumber>
          <RefNumber>3</RefNumber>
          <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
        </InvoiceQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Side note, qbXML version `2.0` is from QuickBooks `2003` (e.g. 14+ years old) so you might want to bump that up a bit to something newer:

```
<?qbxml version="2.0"?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't realize the XMLOps tab displays the information you posted. I was looking at the Request tab on the OSR. Good to know to check the XMLOps tab for sample XML code.